# Why is this simple indexing variable gettng Box-ed in Julia?

Tags: types, julia, type-inference, type-stability

In solving [Problem 10](https://projecteuler.net/problem=10) from Project Euler manually (instead of simply `using Primes`), I implemented a naive Sieve of Eratosthenes in Julia using `BitVector`. It produces the correct output, but when I checked its type stability using `@code_warntype`, I found that `i` was being allocated as `Core.Box`, which affects the type of `psum`, and that in turn  throws the type stability of the whole function away. This is the code used:

```
function primesum(limit::T = 2_000_000) where T<:Integer
    #easy way: using Primes; sum(primes(limit)) 

    #hard way: 
    is_prime_num = BitVector(limit)
    is_prime_num .= true

    psum = zero(limit)
    for i in 2:limit
        if is_prime_num[i]
            psum += i
            multiples_of_i = [k*i for k in 2:(limit÷i)]
            is_prime_num[multiples_of_i] .= false
        end
    end
    psum
end
```

And here is the Variables part of the `code_warntype` output (full output [here](https://pastebin.com/KwmAesSB)):

```
Variables:
  #self#::#primesum
  limit::Int64
  #46::##46#47
  i::Core.Box
  multiples_of_i::Any
  #temp#@_6::Int64
  is_prime_num::BitArray{1}
  psum::Any
  J::Any
  #temp#@_10::Any
```

Overall, a lot of types in the code (including the function's return type) are left as either `Any` or a `where _` type.

I was able to improve speed (almost 10x) and memory (~3x) by changing the `for` loop line to `for i::T in 2:limit` - then, `i` still gets set as a `Core.Box`, but that gets `typeassert`ed to Int64 and doesn't propagate the instability to `psum` and others. But **I'm more interested in why Julia couldn't infer `i`'s type than in speeding up this specific code.** I'm used to type instabilities making sense at least in retrospect, but this one seems pretty clear and simple to infer, so I'd like to know where there is type ambiguity here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A temporary solution is to wrap `i` in `let` block around the comprehension (I have also proposed some small tweaks in your code that are minor cleanups - I have left creation of `multiples_of_i` as this was a core of your question but actually using this variable is also inefficient - it would be better to set `is_prime_num` vector to `false` in appropriate places using a loop):

```
function primesum(limit::Integer = 2_000_000)
    is_prime_num = trues(limit)
    psum = zero(limit)
    for i in 2:limit
        if is_prime_num[i]
            psum += i
            let i=i
                multiples_of_i = [k*i for k in 2:(limit÷i)]
                is_prime_num[multiples_of_i] .= false
            end
        end
    end
    psum
end
```

Hopefully in the long run the issue https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15276 will be fixed and this will not be needed.

Comment: Thanks, good to know it's being tracked as a known Issue. In this case, is it the list comprehension that closes around i internally? Is there some documentation about how exactly the comprehensions are implemented?

Comment: AFAIK the only place you can find how comprehensions are lowered is in julia-syntax.scm file. Relevant code starts in line 2327 of this file. It is a hard read though.

Comment: That looks fascinating. Definitely needs a thorough reading and contextual knowledge, but the scm files all look a lot better structured and more readable than I'd expected. Thanks for the answer and for the pointer.